# How to make an array with objects, where the key of the object will be the value from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays: In array A objects are stored, in array B numbers. I need to compare these arrays and create a new one so that it should looks like:
an array of objects in which the key is a value from array B, and the value must be an array of values from array A
I implemented the logic as shown below, but I'm sure there is an easier solution to this problem.

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 15, prop: 25 },
    { id: 21, prop: 25 },
    { id: 15, prop: 26 },
    { id: 21, prop: 26 },
    { id: 15, prop: 31 },
    { id: 15, prop: 33 },
    { id: 21, prop: 616 },
    { id: 21, prop: 617 }
];
const uniqIds = [15, 21];

// new array should looks like: 
const myArrExample = [
  { '15': [25, 26, 31, 33] },
  { '21': [25, 26, 616, 617] }
]

// My variant which works:
const myArr = uniqIds.map(uniqId => {
  return {
    [uniqId]: arr.filter(itemTwo => {
      if (itemTwo.id === uniqId) {
        return itemTwo.prop;
      }
    }).map(obj => obj.prop)
  };
});

console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it already has a working solution.

Comment: So, what are you asking? To make your _working_ code more efficient? Then you'll need to see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How and why does the result depend on `uniqIds`? Isn’t it sufficient to use the `id`s already present in `arr`? Your algorithm has quadratic runtime complexity. There is a more efficient, linear option.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the ids and use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all the items in the array with the same `id` property, then use `map` to extract the `prop` property of each item.

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 15, prop: 25 },
    { id: 21, prop: 25 },
    { id: 15, prop: 26 },
    { id: 21, prop: 26 },
    { id: 15, prop: 31 },
    { id: 15, prop: 33 },
    { id: 21, prop: 616 },
    { id: 21, prop: 617 }
];
const uniqIds = [15, 21];

const result = uniqIds.map(e => ({[e] : arr.filter(f => f.id == e).map(f => f.prop)}))

console.log(result)
```